# The difference between currentQueue and mainQueue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am looking at the following code:

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (response, data, error) -> Void in
    //code
}
```

I am trying to dig deeper into the apple developer's guide and trying to understand what this all means. I am primarily confused about the part that says `NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()`. When I command click NSOperationQueue, there is another method that can be called, called `currentQueue()`. I was wondering what the differences were.

I looked at the developer's guide and they said `currentQueue()` `Returns the operation queue that launched the current operation.` And `mainQueue()` `Returns the operation queue associated with the main thread.` However, I'm not sure what this actually means. I tried to look up all those terminologies online, and they have so much jargon I have a really hard time understanding them. If you were to explain it to a 15 year old how would you explain it?

Comment: There are lots of queues but only one main queue. The current queue is the one you are in now. So the current queue either is or isn't the main queue.

Comment: It's basically a thread. Here's my book! http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch38.html

Answer (score 0):

The `mainQueue` runs its operations on the main thread, which also is responsible for handling your application's events in its runloop.  Examples of events would be touches, motion, a timer firing, or UI requests.

The `currentQueue` may or may not be the same as the `mainQueue`.  An operation can use `currentQueue` to determine what queue it is running on.

The purpose for running an operation on a different queue is to not delay or preempt more critical interactive tasks (such as scrolling or typing) with longer-running less critical background tasks such as downloads or image processing.

You can read more about queues in the [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)